# Transfer information between two Entity in core data without relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

please please please someone help me

I use my code in core data,
I have two Entity, and Each Entity is in a different view.

The first Entity:

**Entity1**
firstname
lastname
title
phone
image

The second Entity:

**Entity2**
firstname
lastname

How can I transfer information from **Entity1**  to **Entity2** ?
I do not use a relationship between them

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the same data in two entities without a relationship you're probably doing something wrong. If you have different demands on how to display the data on different views, it's better to create two new models that both process the data from that entity.

However, if you insist on having the data in two core data entities, you can always modify your save and update functions (which you probably created) to change the data from the second entity as well.